# Xamarin.Form could not load Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I am blocked with a strange error while building the Android project in a Xamarin.Forms solution.

When I build the Android project I get the following error:

> Exception while loading assemblies: System.IO.FileNotFoundException:
>   could not load assembly 'Xamarin.iOS, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8404fff9cb79065'

Has anyone encountered a similar issue?

Answer (score 1):

On MacOS, Visual Studio 2017 community
I noticed, after updating Xamarin to latest packages most of time rebuild fails with same error, so I clean the solution, exit visual studio, reopen & build the solution !
Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

Solved. There was a reference to a project that was referencing Xamarin.Ios just removing the reference the project now compiles

Comment: Hi Zeta, I'm struck in a similar kind of situation. Can u explain how did u remove that reference??